# Application cannot be installed in the default install location (all apps)

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I am updating 30 apps, and they are all giving me this error. I'm trying to update through the normal Play Store. I have tried restarting my phone, no luck.

I have the Samsung Galaxy S2 Skyrocket, Android 4.0.4.

I thought I might be out space, but I checked and I'm good. "Device memory, available: 250MB. USB storage, available: 164MB"

What could be wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure you need more space free than that. Try clearing some more space and try again

Comment: 164 MB is not nearly enough to update 30 apps I'm afaraid. It mightn't be enought to update 2 to be totally honest. Check the questions around memory and low storage space on here and hopefully you'll find a solution.